# Azure AD B2C - skipping the last step of email verification

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are leveraging Azure AD B2C custom policies for our multi-steps sign up process. The first step is about getting user info (first name, last name) and email address. We also enforce email verification during this first step.

The email verification has multiple steps: user enters his email, Azure sends the code, user enters the code and clicks on 'Verify code' button then there is a last step where the email has been verified and user still needs to click on the Next button to continue the user journey.

Is this possible to skip the last step? If the email is verified, then user should go straight to next screen of the user journey...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently it isn't possible to skip this last step, since it's the Next click that validates the form fields.